# Drupal 7 custom module does not enable

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules

I am trying to create a custom module (as a content/node type) but it's malfunctioning.

Upon creating the desired .module and .info files, I go into Adminstrator/modules and enable the module. Upon enabling this module, all I see is the adminstrator view expand itself[image: screenshot of the administrator page that renders itself once the custom module is enabled]

Compare this with the regular administrator page that renders itself while carrying out administrative tasks:
[image: SCreenshot of administrative page when one of the custom modules has not been enabled, that is the defacto screen]
It is expected to appear in the new Content types button but it does not, and when I look back into the Modules menu, the node is not enabled, even though I enabled it and saved configuration. 
There are no error reports either and I am using the official Drupal documentation to create a module as a node_example...the code for the same can be obtained at this link:

http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--examples--node_example--node_example.module/7

Anybody with any inputs on what's going wrong here? Most importantly this seems to be an error present in the official documentations for creating a module as a node type!

Comment: The node_example module looks incomplete to me, it doesn't implement [`hook_node_info`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--node--node.api.php/function/hook_node_info/7) which is required to define a new content type

Comment: that was the answer, thanks, how do I upvote you ?

Comment: @Clive where are you seeing that? The Node example module certainly does create a new content type called "Example Node Type" (Machine name: node_example).

Comment: "when I look back into the Modules menu, the node is not enabled" This is just one of many ambiguities in this question (enabled nodes are NOT shown in the modules menu) that makes this question not very constructive.

It sounds like Parijat got his answer (?), however this is really not a very helpful SO question for anyone else.

Comment: @Forest We're talking 2 years ago - node_example has been revised a lot since then. At the time the node_info hook was missing